# Content behind div that slides up with jquery

Tags: jquery, slideup

I am trying to figure out how to have a div slide up and have content display behind the div that slides. The effect will slide up a div with a background image of a garage, and when a button is clicked, the garage "opens" and a form displays where the garage was.

So far I have gotten the div with the garage image to slide up and its working just fine.
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("#garage").slideUp(1500);
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("#garage").slideDown(1500);
  });
});
</script>
<style>
#garage {
height:500px;
width:300px;
background-image:url(garage.jpg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="garage"></div>
<button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
<button class="btn2">Slide down</button>

</body>
</html>
```

So my question is how do I nest a div behind the garage div so a form I already have created can be displayed?

Code Demo here: http://reviewmypractice.com/slideup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute positioning on the form container, and a z-index to make sure it stays behind it.

The HTML:

```
<div id="garage"></div>
<div id="formHolder">All the Form Stuff here.</div>
<button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
<button class="btn2">Slide down</button>
```

The CSS:

```
#garage {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-image:url(http://placehold.it/200x200);
}
#formHolder {
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:25px;
  z-index:-1;    
}
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/gWJL4/).

The jQuery is fine as is.  It should be noted that absolute positioning is in respect to the parent.  You might wrap it all in a container, and set the container's position to relative.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **position:absolute** in your css for **#garage**  which makes it on top your form. So it will slide down and slide up on top of your form.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $("#garage").slideUp(1500);
      });
      $(".btn2").click(function(){
        $("#garage").slideDown(1500);
      });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    #garage {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-image:url('http://reviewmypractice.com/garage.jpg');
    position:absolute;
    }
    #content {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="garage"></div>
    <div id="content">Your form comes here !!
    </div>
    <button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
    <button class="btn2">Slide down</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Check the working [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/4QBev/)

Hope this helps.